# How do I verify that my 3.3v power rail meets the requirements for an Ember EM357 SoC?

Tags: zigbee

I've built a circuit that is going to supply 3.3v to a CEL Meshconnect Mini Zigbee module and now I want to test and verify.  The only two things I know to look for is:
-Make sure it's actually 3.3v
-Find out how much ripple there is

Can any basic oscilloscope tell me how much ripple there is?
How much ripple is too much for a Zigbee SoC?
Are there any other factors(i.e. noise) that I'm not taking into account?
Am I over thinking this?

Comment: Are we to assume that your CEL Meshconnect Mini ZigBee module uses the SoC that you posted in the question itself? Are their other components on the module other than the SoC? If so, you should revise your question, since the module will consume more power than just what the SoC draws.

Comment: You shouldn't accept an answer so quickly, to stimulate discussion on the site and encourage others to respond. 24 hours is the usual 'grace period' before acceptance; upvotes and downvotes can and should be used liberally.

Comment: Yes, the EM357 SoC is part of the Meshconnect module.  Yes there are components other than the SoC.  I checked through the datasheets for both the module and the SoC and all I could find was that they both require a voltage ranging from 2.1v to 3.6v.  Both datasheets say the same thing and does not specify ripple limits.
http://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/EM35x.pdf
http://www.cel.com/pdf/datasheets/MeshConnect_EM357_Mini_Modules_DS.pdf

Answer (score 2):

It's more important to know how much current the module can draw. If your DC source isn't up to the task, the module will collapse the rail and all sorts of interesting behaviour can ensue (hiccupping, brown-out, etc.)

Industry practices for power supply ripple measurements *must* be done with a short probe (no long ground lead) or a direct-connect coax with proper termination, with 20 MHz bandwidth limiting turned on, and a combination of ceramic and electrolytic capacitors at the measurement point to attenuate CM noise and give you a 'true' indication of what the ripple is. In industry, it's common to use a 10 microfarad electrolytic capacitor in parallel with 100nF ceramic.

How much ripple your module can actually tolerate is hard to judge unless the manufacturer has specified it. Less is generally better when it comes to microcontroller-based gadgets, especially ones that do a lot of analog-to-digital conversion.

Comment: According to the CEL datasheet, the maximum amount of current draw would be 150mA when transmitting.  The power supply chain starts with 24VAC from an HVAC air handler to a thermostat.  The thermostat then does the AC/DC conversion down to ~3.8VDC.  From the thermostat, my circuit uses a 1uF ceramic input cap to a MCP1703 and a 10uF ceramic output cap to the module.  Unfortunately, I'm venturing into the embedded world from software, so my power supply design skills are limited which is why I'm looking to verify.  Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The ripple limit should usually come from the datasheet, manufacturer communication and/or your EMI requirements.

In order to determine how much noise you have on Vcc, do a popper measurement and read of the Vpp. Sounds simple, right?

The best paper I know of that describes how to do this measurement is this one: http://www.electrical-integrity.com/Quietpower_files/Quietpower-21.pdf

In short: Use a coax cable soldered directly to your board. Run the 50R coax into your oscilloscope set to 50R input impedance. Select AC-coupling. A bandwidth that is adequate (minimum 500 MHz). And infinite persistence.

If you make the measurement using a high impedance probe with a long "pig-tail" for ground - you may have extra noise not related to your Vcc noise picked up. When in doubt, always do the null-experiement: touch the probe tip to the ground point, so both tip and ground of the probe touches the same point on the board. If you don't get a flat line, something is being picked up by inductive coupling into the loop formed by probe and ground lead.

So do you have too much noise? Suppose the datasheet of this device calls for 3.3V +/-5% for the Vcc supply. That means you have +/-165mV as the limit. Let's assume you have a 2% accuracy of your DC regulator. And let's assume you have a 0-1% distribution drop in the connections between the regulator and the device (cables, connectors, traces, filters etc.). That leaves 2% to the AC-noise/ripple or +/-66mV (132mVpp).

If you are designing a supply for a daughter card module, you really should measure the voltage on the module using this principle. Note that you may very well find that the module was not well designed and there is nothing you can do on your board to fix it. That is one of the downsides of using modules.

Answer (score 0):

CEL has an application note now: [ZICM35xSPx Hardware Design Guidelines](http://www.cel.com/pdf/appnote/ZICM35xSPx_Hardware_Design.pdf)

It specifies +/- 0.3Vpp ripple.